# iOS search and replace PDF string

Tags: ios, pdf, quartz-2d, tex

Is it possible to search and replace a known string from a **PDF** with `Objective-C/Quartz 2D`?

I've some nice formatted PDF with tabular data, created with **Latex** (and generated with pdflatex). Every pdf will have a placeholder string, something like XXXXXX that I would like to change programmatically.

This strings will be replaced only by other numbers.

I'm aware that the PDF could be an editable form, but i don't want it because i prefer to leave all the fonts and formatting as they're typeset by Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to search and replace text in PDF files using Quartz 2D. Quartz 2D offers a read only low level interface for reading PDF files. While searching can be implemented on top of it, although with much effort, modifying the files and replacing text is not possible.

Comment: but what about reading that from a template and writing back to another new PDF context and at that time, changing the content?

Comment: Theoretically it is possible but practically it is almost impossible to reproduce the original formatting using the Quartz methods.